# Column relation without composition in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have a Machine table and an Application table. In my model , an application runs on a machine so application includes machine reference on it. But machine does not know which applications are run on itself.

So my class definitions are like this:

```
class Application{

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH})
     @JoinColumn(name = "machine_id",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
     Machine machine
}

class Machine{
     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     int id 
}
```

So I want that, if I delete one machine, all of its applications should be deleted.

Is there any possible ways without adding applications list into the Machine class?

Comment: If you want to delete a machine, how your machine knows about the applications running on it?.

Comment: from the other relation. I thought that, JPA may contain a relations map when the application starts. With this, the engine will know that there is a relationship with application and machine from the annotation manyToOne in Application. I just want to do an inverse relation in here without  any extra codes

Answer (score 0):

try below JPQL

```
query = entityManager.createQuery("select o from Application o where o.machine.id = :machineid");
query.setParameter("machineid", 100);

List<Application> obs = (    List<Application>)query.getResultList();
```

this query will return all the Application running on perticular machine with given ID and delete these Applications.

Comment: Any code samples?How am I gonna put that HQL? any annotations specified for this or am I gonna do that manually?

Comment: modified answer have a look

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @Real, you might also use bulk updates, first deleting the Applications and then the Machine:

```
Query removeApplications = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Application a WHERE a.machine.id = :machineid");
removeApplications.setParameter("machineid", machineIdToBeDeleted);
removeApplications.executeUpdate();

Query removeMachine = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Machine m WHERE m.id = :machineid");
removeMachine.setParameter("machineid", machineIdToBeDeleted);
removeMachine.executeUpdate();
```

Do not delete the other way round, you will probably get a contraint violation exception.

**EDIT** - the proper JPA way of doing this, would be to make the relation bidirectional and cascade the removals. For this, you would need to add a list of applications to the `Machine` class and add the corresponding cascade attribute, but since you explicilty asked how to do it without adding it, I proposed bulk updates.

Here is how it would look with the cascade:

```
Machine machine = entityManager.find(machineId);
entityManager.remove(machine);
```

Comment: Sure I can do that, I actually knew there is a way like that. But I expected that JPA would do it instead. Because in the comment under the question that I have written, JPA may have a relations map and that relation could be used from the definition in Application class. But I am not sure that it is doable

Comment: @Neron - there actually is a way, but it would involve making the relation bidirectional, which you excluded in your question. Please see the edit.